# table view not loading nib when cell is selected

Tags: iphone

i have the following code

```
 if ([[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath].textLabel.text isEqualToString: @"added"]) {
    NSLog (@"hello");
    FinalViewController *anotherViewController = [[FinalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FinalViewController" bundle:nil];
    NSLog (@"hello2");

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES];
    [anotherViewController release];
    NSLog (@"hello3");
```

and it does absolutely nothing on user click. when testing it, all logs appear so im not sure where the problem is located.

Comment: Does the "anotherViewController" return itself? How does the initWithNimName function look like?

Comment: i have this exact same code in another table and it works fine however once i add it to this part it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.navigationController` may be nil.  How was the table view controller added to the navigation controller?

Comment: i solved it it because i forgot to add the navigational controller to the view .

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if you have imported the header file on the top?
And why don't you try to use bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle] ?